# @EnableAutoConfiguration on test context

Tags: spring-boot, testing, spring-bean

I have project where I'm developing a spring auto configuration module.

I'm using a test configuration class (in test classpath),
In this class we are using  `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyTestContext {

}
```

In each of the test classes I'm using it the following way:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyTestContext.class})
```

it looks like context is created correclty and test pass.

My Question is: 
- Is it good practice to use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on a test context ?
- what is the real effect of doing so ?